# Given a lat/lng, find every circle that the lat/lng is in

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have a list geoshape documents like this:

```
{
    "location" : {
        "type" : "circle",
        "coordinates" : [-45.0, 45.0],
        "radius" : "8000m"
    }
 }
```

Given a lat/lng, I want to find all the documents that this lat/lng is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `geo_shape` query like this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "location": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "point",
              "coordinates": [ -77.03653, 38.897676 ]   <-- lon/lat to search
            },
            "relation": "contains"                      <-- use the contains relationship
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the `coordinates` parameter make sure to set longitude before latitude and not the other way around (thanks GeoJSON)

Comment: Were you able to try this out?

Comment: Just tried it out. You can remove `"relation": "contains" `, as it defaults to `intersects`. For a point query, the default works.